# Android Recyclerview's last item gets updated by updating the first item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, position

There is a Recyclerview in my activity. it has always 10 items. Recyclerview's item has two buttons witch each one's click listener is defined in `onBindViewHolder` method of adapter class. after clicking any of the items's buttons it calls a callback method witch is implemented in activity's `onCreate` method. The callback method passes `adapterPosition` to activity an activity returns a long value witch I update button's text with that. 
The problem is when I click the first item's button of the recyclerview, it updates the first and the last item's text. First I used `position` but then changed it to `adapterPosition` or `layoutPosition`, but it didn't worked. sometime the one before last item gets updated and sometimes the last one gets updated with the updating of the first item

**activity's onCreate code**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videocrop)

    var segmentAdapter = SegmentAdapter(10)
    var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    videoCropRecyclerView.adapter = segmentAdapter
    videoCropRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    segmentAdapter.onSegmentSelectedListener = object : OnSegmentSelectedListener {
        override fun onSelectFrom(index: Int): Int? {
            return 12345
        }

        override fun onSelectTo(index: Int): Int? {
            return 54321
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter class code**

```
class SegmentAdapter(var segments: Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SegmentAdapter.SegmentViewHolder>() {

    var onSegmentSelectedListener: OnSegmentSelectedListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SegmentViewHolder =
            SegmentViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.videocrop_segment_item, parent, false))

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = segments

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SegmentViewHolder, position: Int) { 
        holder.from!!.setOnClickListener {
            holder.from!!.text = onSegmentSelectedListener!!.onSelectFrom(holder.adapterPosition)
        }
        holder.to!!.setOnClickListener {
            holder.to!!.text = onSegmentSelectedListener!!.onSelectTo(holder.adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    class SegmentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var from: Button? = null
        var to: Button? = null

        init {
            from = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoCropSegmentItemFromButton)
            to = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoCropSegmentItemToButton)
        }
    }
}
```

**Callback Interface Code**

```
interface OnSegmentSelectedListener {
    fun onSelectFrom(index:Int):Int?
    fun onSelectTo(index:Int):Int?
}
```

when I click the first item's button and its text becomes "0"
[image]

then I scroll down to the last item and I see the last item is also updated

[image]

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203508/recyclerview-first-and-last-item-are-changed-when-clicking-only-one) question but it wasn't helpful.

I would be very thankful if somebody helps me

Answer (score 1):

Your `onBindViewHolder` method is not handling recycled views.  You need to set the text every time in `onBindViewHolder` based on the backing data, rather than just setting it in the click listener, because you may get an `itemView` re-used from a different item (in this case, the first item where you've changed the text).

Comment: thanks my friend, big time. I did what you said. Moved updates out of click listener and passed the data to adapter instead of returning it from callback method and it works like charm.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Feel free to mark the answer as accepted to help others who might encounter the issue as well